# Jackson @JsonFormat date without double quotes

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have this POJO :

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Test {
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyyMMdd")
    private Date date;
}
```

and I got json like this:

```
{"date": 20221201}
```

the date value should be an string. but i can not change anything, it's passed from other service.

it can't be parsed. the date property is always 1970-01-01.

how do i parse a date string without quotes?? is there any way to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Is it mandatory for you to use obsolete `Date` class? Most likely you're using JDK 8+ in your project, if so you can switch to the new Time API and replace `Date` with `LocalDate`.

Comment: Please, [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74697152/edit) the question - add your requirement to support multiple patterns `yyyyMMddHHmm` I see in your comment under the removed answer. It's important to specify if you expect to receive helpful feedback. Also, clarify, do you consider an option to transition to the modern time API (since need to make changes in your code base anyway)?